# Solve the equation $\{x\}+\frac{1}{\{x\}}=2+\left\{\frac{1}{[x]}\right\}$.

Tags: real-numbers, fractional-part

**the question**

Solve the equation $\{x\}+\frac{1}{\{x\}}=2+\left\{\frac{1}{[x]}\right\}$, where $[a]$ and $\{ a\}$ represent the whole and fractional parts of the real number $a$ respectively.

**The idea**

I tried getting $\{\frac{1}{[x]}\}$ to a more acceptable form so I tried these cases:

case 1 : if $[x]=0,1,-1$ then the equation would look like this:

$\{x\}+\frac{1}{\{x\}}=2$ which means that $\{x\}=1$ which isn't possible.

case 2 : if $[x]$ isn't $0,1,-1$ then $\frac{1}{[x]} <1 \implies  \left\{ \frac{1}{[x]}\right\}=\frac{1}{[x]}$

From here we simplified the equality to:

$$\{x\}+\frac{1}{\{x\}}=2+\frac{1}{[x]} \implies \frac{{{(\{x\}-1})}^2}{\{x\}}=\frac{1}{[x]}$$

From here I tried using the fact that $\{x\}+ [x]=x$ or get into some inequality but got to nothing useful. Hope one of you can help me! Thank you!

Comment: try looking at the image of $x+\frac{1}{x}$ for $x\in[0,1)$.

Comment: Expanding on prior comment, $\{x\} + \tfrac{1}{\{x\}}$ is periodic mod $1$ and is decreasing (since $x \mapsto x+1/x$ is decreasing on $(0,1]$). Find the min and max values on $(0,1]$, then consider the behavior of $\frac{1}{[x]}$ on each unit interval and whether it will cross the copy of the LHS.

Comment: @BrevanEllefsen Thank you so much for your idea! Is there any way to explain it without functions?

Comment: $2<2+\frac{1}{[x]}\leq3$ So you can calculate when the left hand side will be in that range. $[x]$ and $\{x\}$ are completely independant in your equation (you can treat them as different variables where one is between $0$ and $1$ and the other is a natural number).

Comment: @VincentBatens $2<\{x\}+\frac{1}{\{x\}} \leq 3$ and $0 \leq \{x\}<1$ => $1<\frac{1}{\{x\}} \leq 3$ which will make it $\frac{1}{3}$ \leq \frac{1}{\{x\}}  <1 $ . What should i do next?

Comment: In case 1, if $[x]=0$ then $\frac{1}{[x]}$ will be undefined

Comment: @IONELABUCIU what is the source of the question?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Let

$$ x = a + b \quad$$

Where $a \in \mathbb{Z}, b \in \mathbb{R} \quad 0 \leq b \lt 1$, We have integer part $a$ and fractional part $b$

Now we get

$$b + \frac{1}{b} = 2 + \{\frac{1}{a}\}$$

$$ \implies a,b \neq 0 \quad$$

#### Case 1

When $a=\{-1, 1\}$, we have $\{\frac{1}{a}\} = 0$, which implies $b=1$ but we have $0 \lt b \lt 1$, hence no solutions exists when $a=\{-1, 1\}$

#### Case 2

When $a \geq 2$, we have $\{\frac{1}{a}\} = \frac{1}{a}$

$$b + \frac{1}{b} = 2 + \frac{1}{a}$$

$$ ab^2 + a = 2ab + b $$

$$ ab^2 + b(-2a-1) + a = 0$$

Now this a quadratic in terms of $b$

$$ b = \frac{2a+1 \pm \sqrt{4a + 1}}{2a} $$

Now we use the inequality by which $b$ was defined

$$ 0 \lt 1 + \frac{1 \pm \sqrt{4a + 1}}{2a} \lt 1 $$

Solving which yields

$$0 \lt 4a^2$$

Hence there exists a value of $b$ s.t. $0 \lt b \lt 1$ for all $a \geq 2$

#### Case 3

When $a \leq -2$, we have $\{\frac{1}{a}\} = \frac{1}{a} - \lfloor \frac{1}{a} \rfloor$

As $a \leq -2$, we get $\lfloor \frac{1}{a} \rfloor = -1$

Therefore $\{\frac{1}{a}\} = \frac{1}{a} + 1$

Now we have

$$b + \frac{1}{b} = 2 + \frac{1}{a} + 1$$

$$ab^2 + a = 3ab + b$$

$$ab^2 + b(-3a - 1) + a = 0$$

Solving the quadratic again we get

$$ b = \frac{3a+1 \pm \sqrt{5a^2 + 6a + 1}}{2a} $$

Using the inequality again we get

$$ 0 \lt \frac{3a+1 \pm \sqrt{5a^2 + 6a + 1}}{2a}  \lt 1 $$

Solving the inequality you get

$$5a^2 + 5a + 2 > 0$$

Which is true for all values of $a$, hence there exists $b$ s.t. $0 \lt b \lt 1$ for all $a \leq -2$

#### Answer

There exists a solution for all $x \leq -2$ and $2 \leq x$

#### Method

A common technique to solve problems involving questions about whole part and fractional part of a number is to write the number in the form $x=a+b$ and then proceed to solve some diophantine equation as done above

Comment: Now it seems correct

Answer (score 4):

I think if you turn to $x=n+p ,  \ 0\le p <1, n=[x]$ it show, there is no negeative solution $$ \frac{{{(\{x\}-1})}^2}{\{x\}}=\frac{1}{[x]}\\ (p-1)^2=\frac np
$$so if $x<0 \to [x]=n=-1,-2,-3,...$and $$(p-1)^2=\frac {0 \le p<1 }{(-) } \  <0 \to 
 no-solution$$ and for $x>0$  we have $$1\le x<2  \to n=1 \to (p-1)^2=\frac { p }{1 } \to p^2-3p+1=0 \to p\sim 1.38 \to x=n+p=1.382\\
2\le x <3 \to n=2 \to (p-1)^2=\frac p2 \to   x=\frac 52\\
3\le x <4 \to n=3 \to (p-1)^2=\frac p3 \to x\sim 3.56\\ \vdots$$

Comment: @Khorotash Thank you so much for your answer! This means that there are infinitely solutions?

Comment: @IONELABUCIU: yes it seems there are infinitely  positive soltions.

Comment: @IONELABUCIU After you ask a question here, if you get an acceptable answer, you should "accept" the answer by clicking the check mark $\checkmark$ next to it. This scores points for you and for the person who answered your question. You can find out more about accepting answers here: [How do I accept an answer?](http://meta.math.stackexchange.com/questions/3286/), [Why should we accept answers?](http://meta.math.stackexchange.com/questions/3399/), [What should I do if someone answers my question?](https://math.stackexchange.com/help/someone-answers).

Comment: There is some mistake. You have forgotten that we take only the fractional part of $1/[x]$, which yields an extraneous solution for $n=1$. Note that 1.382 is not a solution, as shown in the other answer

Comment: Also, there are negative solutions, see my answer.

Comment: @DS: you are right, there is negative solution too. I had a mistake.

Answer (score 2):

Simplifying yields $$\frac{(\{x\} - 1)^2}{\{x\}} = \left \{ \frac 1{\lfloor x \rfloor  } \right\}$$

Note that **we can not discard negative solutions** since the fractional part is **defined** as lying between $0$ and $1$, so the RHS *is* positive.

We divide this into cases:

1. Obviously, $0\le x<1$ gives a zero denominator inside the fractional part in RHS, so it's impossible.
2. For $\{x\} = 0$, the LHS denominator gives zero, which is again impossible. Hence, no solution is an integer.
3. For $1<x<2$, RHS is zero, which is impossible.
4. For $x>2$, we can ignore the fractional part of the RHS. Then, we have a quadratic in $\{x\}$ (note that $\{x\}$ and $\lfloor x \rfloor$ are independent of each other):
   $$f(\{x\})=\lfloor x \rfloor\{x\}^2 - \{x\}(2\lfloor x \rfloor+1) + \lfloor x \rfloor = 0$$
   Since the RHS is a continuous function in $\{x\}$, and $f(1) = -1$ and $f(0) = \lfloor x \rfloor>0$, there exists a solution in $(0,1)$, which can be found by the quadratic formula. Good. (The other root is greater than 1, as found by Vieta's formulae).
5. For $-1<x<0$, the RHS is zero, again impossible.
6. For $x<-1$, $$\left \{ \frac 1{\lfloor x \rfloor  } \right\} = \frac 1{\lfloor x \rfloor  } + 1$$
   Again, we get a quadratic in $\{x\}$:
   $$g(\{x\}) = \lfloor x \rfloor\{x\}^2 - \{x\}(3\lfloor x \rfloor+1) + \lfloor x \rfloor = 0$$
   By analogous reasoning, $g(0) = \lfloor x \rfloor <0$ and $g(1) = -\lfloor x \rfloor - 1 >0$, hence there exists a solution in $(0,1)$. (By Vieta's formulae, the other solution is greater than 1).

In conclusion, $\exists$ exactly one solution for $\lfloor x \rfloor$ **if and only if** $|\lfloor x \rfloor| \ge 2 \iff \lfloor x \rfloor \ge 2 \text{ or } \lfloor x \rfloor \le -2$.

---

For example, some of the solutions found in case 4 (by Quadratic formula) are

- For $\lfloor x \rfloor = 2$, $x = 2.5$.
- For $\lfloor x \rfloor = 3$, $x \approx 3.566$

  and so on.

Some of the solutions found in case 6 (by Quadratic Formula) are:

- For $\lfloor x \rfloor = -2$, $x = -1.5$
- For $\lfloor x \rfloor = -3$, $x \approx -2.549$

  and so on.